# ANDROID STUDIO - how to make a backup copy of the project

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I make a backup copy of the project in ANDROID STUDIO. I tried to just copy the folder of the project, but I had problems with the assembly of the project. My application does not work properly.

`build.gradle` files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ss.new_my_wid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by problems with the assembly ?

Comment: Have you tried Git ?

Comment: you can use git > 


  https://github.com/

Comment: You should not have problems. How did you import your project later on ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem, unless it depends on a library relative to the project.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: Use Github/bitbucket

Comment: Your probably trying to open your project copied from another machine, whose paths depends on that machine. So yeah, use your IDE's build-in `Git` integration instead!

Comment: >What do you mean by problems with the assembly ?  I run copy my project (SHIFT+F10) and my app does not work properly.

Comment: Are you running it from another machine after copying? Or are you depending on some libraries? Post your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: No I run copy of project in my machine

Comment: I post build.gradle files

Comment: During compilation, what errors does the android studio tell you exactly?

Comment: It seems fine. You should also post the error log because we're kind'a poking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your AndoridStudioProjects folder and find your project.
convert to zip file and save in somewhere
extract and import project to android studio whenever you need,it will work.

Comment: There's no difference to just copying the project folder and zipping it. OP is asking why he can't compile it afterwards.

Comment: the original version of the project is working correctly, and a copy is not working properly. (Activities in my app run themselves without calling or the application may not start at all)

Comment: Copy you project folder and paste it into any location you liked. But then you need to rename the copied folder. After that you import the copied project.

Comment: it will also contains billions of files you don't need to backup, there has to be a better way

Answer (score 12):

In your Android Studio go to File Menu and choose Export to Zip File, simple as that. In case your backUp procet is not working just add missing depends. That is all...

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just wondering this myself so tried it out. 
This is how I decided to work it

TO BACKUP

1./ Create a new folder in your Android Studio Projects folder called "!Backups" (optional but easier to navigate when it comes to unzipping & retrieval, however you may choose to put your backups external drive too for obvious reasons)

2./ Click File > Export to Zip File

2b/ If step 1 done, double click on "!Backups" folder

2c/ pick appropriate backup name (ProjectYYMMDD?)

2d/ OK

TO RECOVER

1./ Find folder using windows explorer...
 C:\ > Users > {yourDeviceName} > Android Studio Projects > "!Backups" ... (I keep a shortcut to the Android Studio Projects) on my desktop to make this easier)

2./ Right click project  > Extract All

2b/ Delete last part of path (/ProjectYYMMDD)

2c/ Extract

2d/ Rename extracted folder to desired project name

2e/ Drag folder from backups to AndroidStudioProjects folder

TO USE

1./ Open Android Studio - Open Existing Studio Project

2./ C:\ > Users > {yourDeviceName} > Android Studio Projects

3./ Select restored project folder and open
Icon will be different but will change to normal once it becomes a built project according to android studio

This worked when I tested it so should work for all.
If not , please forgive me, I'm fairly new at all this

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.0. The first two steps (Backup and Recover) works fine. To use, the third step, from the menu: File > New > Import Project..., and selected the recovered project folder. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In the **latest Android Studio 4.1**

1. Got to File menu
2. Click on manage IDE Settings
3. Click on sub-menu "Export to ZIP file..."
4. Add backup file name and select destination path
5. Click on "OK"

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 3.5

Original project: JetFighter001

Menu:  File/Export to Zip File  Change name of Zip file to JetFighter002.

Unzip file.

Close Project Jetfighter001 in AndroidStudio.

Welcome to Android Studio appears on screen.

Click on "Import project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)"

Select the unzipped directory Jetfighter002.

It all worked!

I used before "Open Existing Project" but did not work well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** :
in android studio 4.2.2
File > Export > Export to zip file

**Solution 2** :
go to your directory of your project and use Winrar Software for make your folder to zip file

Attention: solution 1 remove all build file and reduce zip file size increase  **i recommended use solution 1**

[image]